# RxJS 'CombineLatest' that errors if all inputs aren't immediately available

Tags: rxjs

I often use `combineLatest` to combine 3 or 4 Observables to calculate a simple condition.

If one of the 'combined' Observables doesn't emit then this will block until it does. It can be very tricky to debug if later down the line something that has always emitted immediately stops emitting.

Side-note: I'm specifically needing this for UI related logic, where there may be observables that represent things like screen width / scroll position / etc. So they're supposed to always be there - but if it breaks suddenly (especially on mobile) it's difficult to track down what's blocking it.

So what I need is something like `combineLatestImmediate` that errors if all inputs aren't immediately available. When I say 'available right away' it's typically something that comes from a centralized data store, or a behaviorsubject (which of course will always have a value). But when it breaks...ugh.

Is there a better way than:

```
combineLatest(obs1, obs2, obs3)
        .pipe(timeoutWith(0, throwError('Expected obs all to be available')))
```

or even:

```
// note: take(1) is required or the wrong observable
// may get reported if the source hasn’t closed
combineLatest(obs1.pipe(take(1), timeoutWith(0, throwError('obs1 has no value'))),
              obs2.pipe(take(1), timeoutWith(0, throwError('obs2 has no value'))), 
              obs3.pipe(take(1), timeoutWith(0, throwError('obs3 has no value'))));
```

You could put a non zero value for timeout if you wanted a grace period, or make this into a custom operator. But I'm finding a need more and more for this.

It's a safety / sanity thing, to save time debugging.

Also I'm not looking for `forkJoin` (which [short-circuits](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2427) if any of the inputs are EMPTY). I'm talking about when a value is just not immediately available - usually .

Comment: So you're asking if there's already an operator that does something like this?

Comment: Haha if there is then for sure :-) But I don't think there is - therefore it's more about the best technique. However I feel like this *could* maybe become a supported operator (or the best technique should be mentioned in the docs) because figuring out the problem when you get this is very frustrating. Since Observables don't have a concept of 'ready' so I think maybe timeout is the only good way?